# My CSS messes up my recaptcha

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am developing a website that needs to have a form of spam protection on the contact form. Because of this, I am told I need to use recaptcha to prevent spam.

After creating my form and adding the CSS, I implemented the captcha. For some reason, it seems my styles are messing it up.

Here is a screen shot to show what happens

[image: screenshot]

CSS

```
#formContainer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);

}
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
label {
    color: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 18px !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input, textarea{
    outline:none;
}
    input[type=text]{
        color: #777;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 12px;
        margin-left: 18px;
        width: 290px;
        height: 35px;
    }

    input[type=text]#email{
        margin-left:52px;
    }

    #formComments{
        margin-left:18px;
        height: 115px;
        width:293px;
    }


input[type=submit] {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #609941; /*IE fallback*/
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#609941), to(#609941));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #609941 0%,#609941 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #609941 0%, #609941 100%);
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #66add6;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="formContainer">
<iframe src="http://inspirafs.com/totalira/contactext.asp" frameborder="0" height="650" width="100%" scrolling="no">Sorry your browser does not support IFRAMES.</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: You have very generic CSS rules, you likely want to add more specificity by using classes applied to elements, id's etc, otherwise you're subjecting your CSS styles to all elements of a specific type.

Comment: As it stands this is impossible to answer. The only way this can be answered is if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Liam It's not impossible, I had the same thing happen to me. See my answer below. Yet, I agree that more information should be provided in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you are using the `recaptchalib.php` file.

Basically, it's your `input` styling that's pushing everything down. What you need to do is set up a rule to override your `input` on the captcha element.

Something like this should work:

```
#recaptcha_response_field {
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:auto;
width:auto;
}
```